# YouTube Data API how to upload more then seven videos

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload upload 1000 videos to YouTube through the YouTube Data API directly.

Have tried the YouTube Data Api service, but unable to load more than 7 videos.

Comment: Have you managed to get more quota?

Answer (score 4):

The YouTube Data API has a cost based quota.  By default when you create your project you are given 10000 quota points to use.   If you check the [Quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) you will find that Video.Insert costs 1600 quota points.

10000 / 1600 = 6,25

So using the default quota you can max upload 6 videos per day.

The solution is to go to google cloud console and request a quota extension.  Be patient it can take some time to get approved for your extension.

You may want to just ask for 2 million see what they say.